# Array printing wrong in C

Tags: c, linux-kernel, printf

I initialized this 2D array:

```
#define ROW 3
#define COL 2

int _main_(void)
{

    char a[ROW][COL]=
    {
    {'@', '.'},
    {'.', '.'},
    {'.', '.'}
    };
```

And I printed it like:

```
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            kprintf("%c", a[i][j]);
        }
            kprintf("\n");
    }
```

Output:

```
@.
  ..
    ..
```

But I want it to be:

```
@.
..
..
```

What am I doing wrong? (C newbie)

Comment: What is `kprintf`? Your code would work just fine with `printf`. If printf fails, just `#include <stdio.h>` at the top.

Comment: Or `putchar()`.

Comment: Apparently, your display needs CR (carriage return) as well as LF (line feed, aka newline) at the end of a line.  Add `\r` before the `\n`; that should generate the display you want as a quick fix.  It probably isn't a good long-term answer, though.

Comment: kprintf is the kernel's print function. When I use printf it gives me an "undefined reference" error.

Comment: @pmcg521 That's because you haven't included the thing we told you to.

Comment: @pmcg521 Have you included `stdio.h`?

Comment: What is the environment in which you are running your program? `kprintf` is not a standard function, but is specific to your execution environment. (Ps. Your problem has nothing to do with arrays. Try `kprintf("hello\nworld\n")` to prove that.)

Comment: OK; then I've no idea.  What you're seeing is a result of the newline not moving the cursor position back to the start of line.  In many circumstances, adding `\r` would resolve that, but if it doesn't work, I've no idea what levels of interpretation and terminal setting are going on and what you need to change to fix it.

Comment: @Robᵩ the op maybe on linux kernel

Comment: @Raindrop7 - afaik, there is not `kprintf` in the Linux kenrel. Only `printk`. There are `kprintf`s in the BSD, OSX, and QNX kernels, but we need to know which one before giving useful advice.

Comment: @Robᵩ: ok that is it

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestions everyone. The problem was that I did not include the carriage return "\r". Now it prints perfectly! Special thanks to @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `kprintf("\n");` to `kprintf("\r\n");`

Normally the `\n` (newline) works by itself. But for some reason you need `\r` (carriage return) for whatever hardware you're working with.

Comment: Conventionally, the CRLF sequence is `"\r\n"` — as found in Windows text files and most Internet text protocols (e.g. http, smtp, ftp, …)